# Make text Blink in AndEngine GlES2.0

Tags: android, andengine

**WHAT I WANT:** I want my text to appear character by character and when entire text is visible, I want entire text to blink.

**WHAT I HAVE DONE:**

```
Text displayText = new TickerText(WIDTH / 2 - ((displayTxt.length() / 2) 
    * FONT_SIZE_LARGE) / 2 - FONT_SIZE_LARGE, HEIGHT / 2, mPlokFontLarge, 
    displayTxt, new TickerTextOptions(HorizontalAlign.CENTER, 4),
    vertexBufferObjectManager);
scene.attachChild(displayText);
```

This code adds the text which is in string `displayTxt` and then make it appear character by character. Now to make it blinking i made a `LoopEntityModifier`

```
final LoopEntityModifier blinkModifier = new LoopEntityModifier(
    new SequenceEntityModifier(new FadeOutModifier(0.25f), new FadeInModifier(0.25f)));
```

But i can't add this to `displayText`.

Also i checked out [this link which tells how to do so](http://www.andengine.org/forums/development/how-to-display-blinking-text-t1326.html), but the problem is, it is for GLES1.0

Any help is appreciated. Also, I am very new to AndEngine, so please forgive it I am going wrong and guide me. Also if you can point me to relevant tutorials, it will be appreciated

Comment: why can't you add this to `displayText` ?

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to add any modifier to your text using something like

```
displayText.registerEntityModifier(yourModifierHere)
```